# mudar o estilo de uma tag dentro de outra tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

dentro de uma DIV tem três A e um IFRAME, eu quero mudar o estilo do A sem que interfira no IFRAME, mas eu preciso fazer isso em javascript, pois estou desenvolvendo uma api de um único arquivo e não quero que as pessoas baixem um .css, como é o caso do bootstrap.

PS: Não usarei nenhuma api ou dependência como o JQuery, ou outros, pois as pessoas que forem baixar irão precisar de mais um arquivo.

Comment: Pq vc não coloca o estilo direto na tag tipo `<a style="colore:red;">` ou então dentro do `<head>` do su documento vc cria uma tag `<style>` e cloca a classe `a.cor {colore:red;}`. Te falei para colocar a tag `<style>` no Head apenas por boa prática, mas atualmente nem isso precisa mais, vc pode coloca-la em qualquer lugar do documento...

Comment: Porque o objeto teria sido criado completamente por javascript, e quando tocasse nele, mudaria de forma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O css de uma página mãe não é propagado para um iframe filho, então não se preocupe em simplesmente colocar:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div > a').forEach(function(elm){
    elm.style.color = 'white'
});
```

Assim, pegamos todos os `a` dentro de `div` e iteramos com o `forEach`, passando por todos os links.

O seletor `>` faz com que apenas as primeiras ocorrências da tag `a` sejam afetadas pelo estilo.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!